# Trouble calculating probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Machine generates one random integer in range ${[0;40)}$ on every spin.
You should choose 5 numbers in that range.

Then the machine will spit out **5** numbers (*numbers are independent of each other*).

**what is the probability that you will get exactly two numbers correct?**

---

**My logic:**
You should get two of them right. chance of that is: $r = { \left( 1 \over 40 \right)^ 2 }$
You should get 3 of wrong. Chance of that is: $w = { \left( 39 \over 40 \right)^3 }$
As order doesn't matter answer should be: $$ans = { rw \over 2!3!}$$
Simulator tells me I'm wrong. Where is my logic flawed?

**P.s. Machine can spit out duplicates**

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  First of all, are the numbers chosen without replacement? That is, can you get duplicates?  Secondly, where is $\frac 1{40}$ coming from?  If you just choose one number, the chances that the machine also chooses it are $1-\left(\frac {39}{40}\right)^5$ (assuming that you are choosing wih replacement).  If you are choosing without replacement then it should be $\frac 5{40}$  Note that the two values are close but not the same.

Comment: You can get duplicate and you should choose 5 numbers.

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect that fact, don't leave critical information to the comment section.

Comment: I understand that you are choosing $5$ numbers, I just gave the one choice calculation to illustrate.  Now you just have a simple binomial problem

Comment: Thanks I edited it.

Comment: I suggest that the post says that the numbers are integers and that the interval notation is used with a colon or a semi-colon instead of a dash (that can be mistaken by a minus sign).

Comment: Besides the problem with the probability of the machine giving a right number, you must also think about the order at which the right or wrong numbers come out. So, I think there is something missing next to the $2! 3!$ part.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? What is the range of the number generated?

Comment: range is $[0;40)$. by 2 correct I meant that 2 out of 5 numbers you chose will be generated by machine too and the other 3 you chose will not.

Comment: So, the process is: Select 2 integer numbers, the machine produces 5 integer numbers in the range [0,39] - What is the chance that the numbers you selected are in the set the machine produced? If so, please correct your wording on the original post so readers could help.

Comment: @Ertxiem yes, I think you need to write all variations seperately, I can't think of generalization.

Comment: @NoChance No. you select 5 integer numbers in the range [0,39] and machine also generates 5 integers in that range, What is chance that two numbers out of five you selected will be in the set the machine procduced? (other three numbers from your selection shouldn't be in the set)

Comment: @Ika Can you select the same number more than once in anticipation that the machine might do the same? Or are you selecting five distinct numbers?

Comment: Alternatively, can you explain the Simulator's mechanism.

Comment: Also, if the machine picks one of your numbers twice, does that count as two correct picks?

Comment: Anyway, at this point, you have several answers that "could" be correct, depending on how the problem is interpreted. lulu's answer assumes both you and the machine use replacement. Balakrishnan Rajan's answer assumes that you choose five distinct numbers, but if the machine matches your same number twice, it counts twice as a match. My answer assumes the machine is picking with replacement, and you are picking five distinct numbers, and at least two of your numbers have to match numbers picked by the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different errors in your calculation.

- If the numbers you choose are $\ n_1, n_2, \dots, n_5\ $ (I'm presuming these have to be all different), and the numbers generated by the machine are $\ m_1, m_2, \dots, m_5\ $, then $\ \left(\frac{1}{40}\right)^2\ $ is merely the probability that any specified ordered pair of numbers generated by the machine are equal to some given pair of your chosen numbers (e.g. $\ m_1=n_1\ $ and $\ m_2=n_2\ $, for instance).  To allow for the fact that the order doesn't matter, you need to *multiply*, not divide, by $\ 2!\ $—that is, $$\ \mathrm{Prob}\left(\left\{m_1=n_1\, \&\, m_2=n_2\right\}\lor\left\{m_2=n_1\, \&\, m_2=n_1\right\}\right)=2\left(\frac{1}{40}\right)^2\ .$$  But you still haven't counted the cases where some *other* pair of the numbers chosen by the machine ($\ m_4\ $ and $\ m_5\ $, for example) are equal to your $\ n_1\ $ and $\ n_2\ $, let alone any *other* pair of your chosen numbers.
- As clarified in one of your comments, it is possible for *more than $\ 2\ $* of the numbers generated by the machine to match some of those in your hand even when you have only *exactly two* right. If you choose numbers $\ 1,2,3,4,5\ $, for instance, and the machine generates the numbers $\ 6,7,1,8,2,1\ $,  then exactly $\ 2\ $ of your numbers—namely, $\ 1\ $ and $\ 2\ $—are among those generated by the machine, but *three* of those generated by the machine—namely the $\ 2\ $ and the two $\ 1$s—are among those you chose.  Also, once the machine has generated two of the numbers you have chosen, it cannot generate *any* of the remaining $\ 3\ $ you have chosen without increasing the number you've got correct to more than $\ 2\ $.  Thus, for both of these reasons, $\ \left(\frac{39}{40}\right)^3\ $ isn't the probability of your getting $\ 3\ $ wrong.

The easiest way I can see of calculating the probability you're looking for is to treat the accumulating number of matches between the numbers generated by the machine and those you have chosen as an inhomogeneous Markov chain.  Let $\ C\ $  be the set of numbers you have chosen (which I assume to be all distinct), $\ m_1, m_2, \dots, m_5\ $ the numbers generated by the machine, and $\ X_n = \left\vert \left\{m_i\right\}_{i=1}^n\cap C\right\vert, X_0=0\ $. Then $\ \left\{X_n\right\}_{i=1}^5\ $ is a Markov chain whose states and transitions are represented in the diagram below:[image]

The numbers on the links are the transition probabilities, while the numbers inside the circles are the probabilities of the states being reached.  If my arithmetic is correct, the probability that exactly two of your chosen numbers appear amongst those generated by the machine is $\ \frac{2,337}{256,000}\approx 0.091\ $.

**Update:** It turns out there was an arithmetical error in my original calculations, which I have now corrected.  As a check on the result, here's a calculation of the number of sequences of $\ 5\ $ integers in the range $\ 0\ \mathrm{to}\ 39\ $, in which *exactly* two out of a given set, $\ S\ $, of $\ 5\ $ *distinct* such numbers occur.

There are $\ {5\choose2}\ $ different pairs of members of $\ S\ $ that could be the ones that occur in the sequence.

- If these occur exactly once each, then there are $\ 5\ $ positions of the sequence in which the lower of the two could be placed, and for each of these, there are $\ 4\ $ positions where the higher could be placed.  For each of these arrangements the remaining $\ 3\ $ positions have to be each filled with a number not in $\ S\ $, which can be done in $\ 35^3\ $ ways. Thus, there are total of $\ 5\cdot\ 4\cdot 35^3\ $ sequences of this type.
- If one of these numbers is duplicated in the sequence, there are $\ {5\choose 3}\ $ combinations of positions in the sequence where they can be placed, and for each of these there are $\ 6\ $ possible ways in which the two numbers can fill them (the non-duplicated number can be either of the two, and it can be in any of the three positions).  The remaining two positions have to be filled by numbers not in $\ S\ $, which can be done in $\ 35^2\ $ ways. Thus there are a total of $\ {5\choose3}\cdot6\cdot35^2\ $ sequences of this type.
- If the two numbers together occur a total of $\ 4\ $ times in the sequence, then there are $\ {5\choose4}\ $ combinations of positions where they can be placed, and there are $\ 2^4-2=14\ $ ways in which the two numbers can fill them.  For each of these, the remaining position in the sequence can be filled in $\ 35\ $ ways by a number not in $\ S\ $.  Thus, there are a total of $\ {5\choose4}\cdot14\cdot35\ $ sequences of this type.
- If all five numbers in the sequence are one of the two, there are $\ 2^5-2=30\ $ ways in which they can be chosen to fill the $\ 5\ $ positions.

Thus the total number of sequences with the desired property is $$\ {5\choose2}\left(5\cdot\ 4\cdot 35^3+{5\choose3}\cdot6\cdot35^2+{5\choose4}\cdot14\cdot35+30\right)\\=9,334,800\ ,$$
and the probability of the machine's generating one of these sequences is $\ \frac{9,334,800}{40^5}=\frac{23,337}{256,000}\ $, as obtained by the Markov chain calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say, you have chosen 5 numbers. Then the odds of the machine generating one of your chosen numbers is $\frac{5}{40}$. This happens twice and it doesn't happen thrice. So this should be $\left(\frac{5}{40}\right)^2\times\left(\frac{35}{40}\right)^3$. Now this could have happened in $\frac{5!}{2! \times 3!}$ (or $5 \choose 2$).

So, is it $\left(\left(\frac{5}{40}\right)^2 \times \left(\frac{35}{40}\right)^3 \times {5 \choose 2} \right)$?

However, the assumption is that you choose distinct numbers in that range. In case, your strategy is to maximize the "correct" score. If you are picking at random without a strategy, then [lulu's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3164437/652935) answer is the one you are looking for.

Comment: I believe the number of ways is $\frac{5!}{2! 3!}$ because exchanging two correct numbers is the same case (already included in the probability).

Comment: Your solution is the most natural one, given the text of the problem. But it is not yet correct. You should replace $5!$ by ${5\choose2}$.

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks Ertxiem and Christian Blatter. In this case, $5 \choose 2$ and $\frac{5!}{2! \times 3!}$ are the same value. I am guessing it's because it can either be a multiset with 3 items and 2 items of two types or choosing 2 trials out of 5 for the "correct" trials. Am I right?

Comment: The binomial form says something like: from 5 items, choose two without replacement, in this case we are selecting the position (order) at which the correct numbers are "split" by the machine. The factorial form says that from all permutations of 5 elements, we are not interested in those that only exchange the order of the 2 correct numbers and we are not interested in those that only exchange the order of the 3 incorrect numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple binomial problem.

Note:  I am assuming that both you and the machine choose with replacement.  That is, either (or both) of you might have duplicates.

For a single choice you make, the probability that the machine also makes it (as one of the $5$ it chooses) is $\psi = 1 - \left( \frac {39}{40}\right)^5$.

As your choices are independent, the answer is then $$\binom 52\times \psi^2\times (1-\psi)^3\approx .0967$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the argument if neither you nor the machine can repeat.

Since all the numbers are equally likely let's assume you chose $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

There are $T = \binom{40}{5}$ total ways the machine can choose its five numbers. Let's count how that choice might overlap with yours.

There are

$$
\binom{35}{5} \text{ choices with } 0 \text{ overlap}
$$

$$
\binom{5}{1}\binom{35}{4} \text{ choices with } 1 \text{ overlap}
$$
$$
\binom{5}{2}\binom{35}{3} \text{ choices with } 2 \text{ overlap}
$$
$$
\binom{5}{3}\binom{35}{2} \text{ choices with } 3 \text{ overlap}
$$
$$
\binom{5}{4}\binom{35}{1} \text{ choices with } 4 \text{ overlap}
$$
$$
1 \text{ choice with } 5 \text{ overlap}
$$

To find the probability of exactly $2$ matches, compute that number as above and divide by $T$, To find the probability of at least $2$ matches, add the probabilites of $0$ and $1$ match and subtract from $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine is choosing with replacement, but the person is choosing five distinct numbers, and if success means two distinct numbers the person chose are picked by the machine, then the problem is much more difficult:

Probability machine chooses five distinct numbers:
$$\dfrac{40!}{35!40^5}$$

Probability machine chooses four distinct numbers (choose the four distinct numbers the machine selected, choose the one number that is repeated twice, permute the multiset to find all possible orders these numbers could be chosen, divide by the total number of ways to choose five numbers):
$$\dfrac{\dbinom{40}{4}\dbinom{4}{1}\dfrac{5!}{1!1!1!2!}}{40^5}$$

Probability machine chooses three distinct numbers (choose the three distinct numbers the machine selected, either one number is repeated three times or two numbers are repeated twice each):
$$\dfrac{\dbinom{40}{3}\dbinom{3}{1}\left(\dfrac{5!}{3!1!1!}+\dfrac{5!}{2!2!1!}\right)}{40^5}$$

Probability machine chooses two distinct numbers (choose the two distinct numbers the machine selected. You can have one number four times and the other once or one number three times and the other twice.):
$$\dfrac{\dbinom{40}{2}\dbinom{2}{1}\left(\dfrac{5!}{4!1!}+\dfrac{5!}{3!2!}\right)}{40^5}$$

So, the probability of you matching exactly two numbers:
$$\begin{align*} & \dfrac{40!}{35!40^5}\cdot \dfrac{\dbinom{5}{2}\dbinom{35}{3}}{\dbinom{40}{5}}\\ + & \dfrac{\dbinom{40}{4}\dbinom{4}{1}\dfrac{5!}{2!}}{40^5}\cdot \dfrac{\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{36}{3}}{\dbinom{40}{5}} \\ + & \dfrac{\dbinom{40}{3}\dbinom{3}{1}\left(\dfrac{5!}{3!}+\dfrac{5!}{(2!)^2}\right)}{40^5}\cdot \dfrac{\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{37}{3}}{\dbinom{40}{5}} \\ + & \dfrac{\dbinom{40}{2}\dbinom{2}{1}\left(\dfrac{5!}{4!}+\dbinom{5}{3}\right)}{40^5}\cdot \dfrac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{38}{3}}{\dbinom{40}{5}} \approx 0.09116015625\end{align*}$$

Note: It is possible for the machine to choose one distinct number, but there is a zero probability that you wind up with two matching numbers, so I ignored that case. To show that my numbers work out though, you can test that the following holds:

$$\dfrac{40!}{35!}+\dbinom{40}{4}\dbinom{4}{1}\dfrac{5!}{2!1!1!1!}+\dbinom{40}{3}\dbinom{3}{1}\left(\dfrac{5!}{3!1!1!}+\dfrac{5!}{2!2!1!}\right)+\dbinom{40}{2}\dbinom{2}{1}\left(\dfrac{5!}{4!1!}+\dfrac{5!}{3!2!}\right)+\dbinom{40}{1} = 40^5$$

(I verified this is true myself using Wolframalpha).

Comment: I believe your conditional probabilities of matching exactly two of the numbers produced by the machine are too small by a factor of ten. When the machine produces five distinct numbers, for instance, there are $\ {5\choose 2}\ $ possible pairs of numbers that you can match.  There are $\ 5\ $ positions in the string you choose where the lower of the two numbers can go, and for each of these, there are four positions where the higher one can go, and there are $\ 35\cdot34\cdot33\ $ ways of choosing the remaining places to be filled with numbers not chosen by the machine.

Comment: Thus, if you choose your sequence randomly, I believe the probability of your matching exactly two of the numbers chosen by the machine in this case would be  $\ \frac{{5\choose2}\cdot5\cdot4\cdot35\cdot34\cdot33}{40\cdot39\cdot38\cdot37\cdot36}\ $.

Comment: Likewise, for the probabilities in the cases when the machine produces $\ 4, 3,\ $ and $\ 2\ $ distinct numbers, respectively, I get  probabilities $\ \frac{{4\choose2}\cdot5\cdot4\cdot36\cdot35\cdot34}{40\cdot39\cdot38\cdot37\cdot36}\ $, $\ \frac{{3\choose2}\cdot5\cdot4\cdot37\cdot36\cdot35}{40\cdot39\cdot38\cdot37\cdot36}\ $, and $\ \frac{{2\choose2}\cdot5\cdot4\cdot38\cdot37\cdot36}{40\cdot39\cdot38\cdot37\cdot36}\ $, respectively.

Comment: When I evaluate your current answer, I get $\ \frac{23,337}{2,560,000}\approx 0.009116015625\ $, and multiplying this by $\ 10\ $ gives the same result that I've obtained by two different methods in my answer to the question.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I updated the formula